# Show/Hide Div Dependant on URL Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If the word email appears in the URL div id='sociallocker' should show and div id ='emaillocker' should hide.

If the word email is not in the URL: div id='sociallocker' should hide and div id='emaillocker' should show.

So:
URL contains email:
Show div: #sociallocker
Hide div: #emaillocker

URL doesn't contain email:
Show div: #emaillocker
Hide div: #sociallocker

Live link: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/

With the current code both div's are showing regardless?

**HTML**

```
<div id="sociallocker">
[sociallocker id="1505"]
</div>


<div id="emaillocker">
[emaillocker]
[/emaillocker]
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {
$("#sociallocker").css(‘display’, ‘none’);
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you need to wait for the ready event, e.g. wrap your js in `$( document ).ready(function(){/*code here*/)`

Comment: No difference @Noface

Comment: can you `console.log(document.location.href)` and share the output here please?

Comment: I've changed the script to: <script type="text/javascript">
console.log(document.location.href)
if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {
$("#sociallocker").css(‘display’, ‘none’);
}
</script>


Is this correct?

Comment: what does the console output with that code? press f12 or open dev tools for your browser and look in console

Comment: Using Chrome, couldn't find it when I searched? https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/

Comment: press f12 and find console https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: I have tried to give you an answer sam please review it if you find difficulties let me know I shall help you to resolve in an answer. and kindly post your url where you use these hash parameters (#emaillocker, #sociallocker) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As per my best understanding, I have tried to simulate your question with fake URL string give you an answer.

You have 2 possibilities of hash params either sociallocker or emaillocker and it will show in URL following way #sociallocker or #emaillocker.

As you have tried to do code in core javascript I have given you an answer in core javascript as well.

Here I suppose that you have below url scheme for example.

**https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/**

```js
// When you do in programming uncomment following line.
//var _href = document.location.href;

// When you do in programming comment following line.
var _href= "https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-for-stack/#sociallocker";

var params = _href.split("#")[1];

var divEmailLocker = document.getElementById("emaillocker");
var divSocialLocker = document.getElementById("sociallocker");

if (params.indexOf("sociallocker") > -1) {
  divSocialLocker.style.display = "block";
  divSocialLocker.style.visibility = "visible";
  divEmailLocker.style.display = "none";
  divEmailLocker.style.visibility = "hidden";
}else if (params.indexOf("emaillocker") > -1) {
  divSocialLocker.style.display = "none";
  divSocialLocker.style.visibility = "hidden";
  divEmailLocker.style.display = "block";
  divEmailLocker.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
div#sociallocker, div#emaillocker{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="sociallocker">
  [sociallocker id="1505"]
</div>


<div id="emaillocker">
  [emaillocker] [/emaillocker]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `show()` and `hide()` of jQuery.

```js
//str="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467845/show-hide-div-dependant-on-url-variable/email";

if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) {  //insted of 'str' use document.location.href
    $("#sociallocker").show();
    $("#emaillocker").hide();
}
else{
    $("#sociallocker").hide();
    $("#emaillocker").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sociallocker">
[sociallocker id="1505"]
</div>


<div id="emaillocker">
[emaillocker]
[/emaillocker]
</div>
```

Comment: Is the script supposed to have a link to this question in it?

Comment: @SamJefferies no, I just put it explain, you can directly use `location.href`, no need of 'str'

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to exactly what I need to copy/paste to avoid any potential mistakes?

Comment: @SamJefferies I updated the answer but don't copy comment(which is useless)

Comment: Thanks,  no luck onsite: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/test-page-2/

Are you familiar with a reason why Wordpress would stop this from working?

Comment: Script fired from a custom genesis js: <script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf("email") >= 0) { 
    $("#sociallocker").show();
    $("#emaillocker").hide();
}
else{
    $("#sociallocker").hide();
    $("#emaillocker").show();
}
</script>

Comment: @SamJefferies so is it giving error or something?(if genesis.js is custome js then you can remove `<script>` and `</script>`)

Answer (score -1):

try

```
document.location.href.includes("email")
```

to check if the word "email" is present in the url

Comment: Thanks so everything else the same apart from the second line?

Comment: E.G. <script type="text/javascript">
document.location.href.includes("email")
$("#sociallocker").css(‘display’, ‘none’);
}
</script>